# Get previous working day

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I need to get previous working date from the current date. For instance if the current day is monday , I need to get the date of Friday .

I have following code to get the previous date  from the current date.

```
-(NSDate*)previousDateFromDate:(NSDate*)date {

NSDate *now = date;
int daysToAdd = -1;

// set up date components
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:daysToAdd];

// create a calendar
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:GregorianCalendar];
return [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];
```

}

How can I achieve this ? Is it by calculating difference of index of the current day ?

Comment: How do you know what the previous working day is? Are you accounting for holidays?

Comment: could use a dateformatter with format "EEE" on the previous date which will give you the day of the week, then just check if its mon - fri, and do something about it if its not (if you dont need holidays accounted for)

Comment: we can ignore the holidays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea and using the weekday number is the way to go, comments in code:

```
-(NSDate*)previousDateFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
   // Get the current calendar
   NSCalendar *currentCal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

   // Get current weekday, Sunday = 1
   NSDateComponents *comps = [currentCal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
   NSInteger weekday = comps.weekday;

   // Determine the number of days to go back, assuming Sat -> Mond should go to Fri
   NSInteger deltaDays = weekday == 1 ? -2 : (weekday == 2 ? -3 : -1);

   // Create componets with the offset
   NSDateComponents *offset = [NSDateComponents new];
   offset.day = deltaDays;

   // Calculate the required date
   return [currentCal dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:date options:0];
}
```

This assumes the current calendar is the Gregorian one, you'll have to figure out if it works for others.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSDate*)previousDateFromDate:(NSDate*)date {

    NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    //[comp weekday] =  1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.

    NSDate * returnDate;

    if([comp weekday] == 1){
        returnDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:(-86400 * 2)];
    }else {
        returnDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:-86400];
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```

Comment: Should never calculate day offsets using fixed intervals.